# After using optional chaining. Problem Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0

Tags: reactjs, axios, jwt, token, mern

After using the optional chain, I've received this problem.

> Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0

```
import axios from 'axios'

const BASE_URL = 'http://localhost:5000/api'
const TOKEN = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('persist:root'))?.user)
    ?.currentUser?.accessToken || null

export const publicRequest = axios.create({
  baseURL: BASE_URL,
})

export const userRequest = axios.create({
  baseURL: BASE_URL,
  headers: { token: `Bearer ${TOKEN}` },
})
```

Edit added:
[image: Edit Image]

Comment: What is inside `persist:root`?

Comment: @SurjeetBhadauriya it's empty for now, as long as i'm not logged in, the program should not acquire the token in localstorage, that is why i'm using optinal chain.

please correct me if i'm doing wrong

Comment: Are you supposed to be parsing twice?  The error is thrown within `JSON.parse`

Comment: By showing us an example of the string that you would expect to be in `persist:root` (if it were not empty), we can help  you further.

Comment: @s_sldiblood, There is no need of doing JSON.parse twice. So just replace your code with `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('persist:root'))?.user?.currentUser?.accessToken || null`

Comment: @jsejcksn I'm using JWT

Comment: @SurjeetBhadauriya I'm getting 403 error when I'm not doing it JSON.parse twice. It seems that I need to go deeper to the object. I need to grab the JWT token, that is why i'm parsing it twice.

Comment: It will be better if you can add `persist:root`. That will make it easy to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```js
const TOKEN = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('persist:root'))?.user ?? null)?.currentUser?.accessToken || null;
```

It is the same as:

```js
const storageItem = localStorage.getItem('persist:root'); // string or null
const parsedObject = JSON.parse(storageItem); // parsed object or null
const parsedUser = JSON.parse(parsedObject?.user ?? null); // parsed user or null
const TOKEN = parsedUser?.currentUser?.accessToken || null; // the token or null
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to parse `persist:root`, this object is set by `redux-persist` library, which is a copy of your redux store. If you want any data from the store, use the `useSelector` hook in your React component.